# Using ON UPDATE CASCADE when update causes duplicate values

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, constraints

In PostgreSQL, I have one master table, ICD9, that is intended to hold unique combinations of cicd9 and cdesc with the constraint of:

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_cdesc UNIQUE (cicd9, cdesc)
```

I have multiple child tables referencing the ICD9 table with:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_icd9 FOREIGN KEY (cicd9, cdesc)
REFERENCES icd9 (cicd9, cdesc) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I can change whatever constraints I need to, but my goal is to use the master table to correct all the misspellings of the child tables. I have not found a good (or any) answer on the internet. The problem is that updating the incorrect spelling in cdesc or the wrong code in cicd9 results in duplicate entries in the master table--so errors are thrown.

What is the best way to do this (I think) relatively common problem?

Note: I am using C# (Net 4.0) within a separate program to address a PostgreSQL 9.1 database server (of which I am the administrator).

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you intend for the "master" table to contain the spelling, you should introduce an artificial key (identity or similar) into the master, and use that as FK in your associated tables. Duplicating description is something to avoid. And for your specific issue, if you get a duplicate value conflict when updating, then it is because the data will cause one (you likely fix a spelling error, where a non-spelling error record already exists) and then you should likely update the data manually/via triggers instead.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Makes sense. I will need to research triggers more. An example would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If `updating` the entry in `icd9` leads to a `unique constraint` violation, then it seems to me like what you would actually want to do in that case is `delete` the entry from `icd9` instead of updating it.

If `deleting` the entry would cause a `FK constraint` violation in the other tables then I would recommend first getting rid of that issue by updating the entries in the child tables to refer to the entry that is causing the `unique constraint` violation (i.e. the 'correct' value that's already there), and then do the `delete` on the 'incorrect' value.

If you wanted to automate this to some degree you could probably create a `pl/pgSQL` function that would:

1. Check to see if any unique constraints would be violated
2. If so, this is a delete candidate
3. Then, check the child tables to see if there are any entries referring to the delete candidate
4. If so, `update` these to point to the row that is 'correct' -- i.e. the one that would lead to the unique constraint violation
5. Then do the `delete` of the row within the `icd9` table

**Note:** You wouldn't want to have the `DELETE` in the constraint `CASCADE`, since you don't want to delete the rows that reference it, but update them to point to the other row in `icd9`.

**Edit:**
To programmatically determine the FK (or other) constraints a table has, you can query the `pg_constraint` table which is part of the `catalog`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html for more details.

You'll probably want to join that with `pg_class` to start with the original table names. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-class.html for more info.

Comment: Is there a way to query the PostgreSQL database for the child tables that depend on this constraint? The obvious goal being to discover which tables to change.

Comment: I did find this by Tom Lane:select confrelid::regclass, af.attname as fcol, 
       conrelid::regclass, a.attname as col from pg_attribute af, pg_attribute a, (select conrelid,confrelid,conkey[i] as conkey, confkey[i] as confkey 
   from (select conrelid,confrelid,conkey,confkey, 
                generate_series(1,array_upper(conkey,1)) as i 
         from pg_constraint where contype = 'f') ss) ss2 
where af.attnum = confkey and af.attrelid = confrelid and 
a.attnum = conkey and a.attrelid = conrelid  AND confrelid::regclass = 'my_table'::regclass AND af.attname = 'my_referenced_column';

Comment: That seems like it should work. You may want to also add the `conname` element throughout that query, which is the name of the actual constraint, although depending on how you're processing things, that may not matter (if you just want to know what the dependent tables are).

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this as a possible solution. I would be most interested in an optimized version of this if anybody's interested. Thanks @Ken for the pointers. (I don't know how to best format this for SO, sorry).

```
internal static void UpdateDxLibraryTx(PhysicalExam.DX newdx, PhysicalExam.DX olddx)
    {
        String Unique_Violation = "23505";

        // nothing to change.
        if (olddx.description == null) return;  

        PhysicalExam.DX oldDx = (PhysicalExam.DX)olddx;

        // the server structure was created in MainWindow on initialization.
        string connect = server.connection_string;

        string update = " update icd9 set cicd9='" + newdx.icd9 + "', cdesc= '" + newdx.description.ToLower().Trim() + "'" +
                " ,chronic ='" + newdx.chronic + "' ,modified='" + DateTime.Now + "'" +
                " where cicd9 ='" + oldDx.icd9 + "'" +
                " and trim(cdesc) ='" + oldDx.description.ToLower().Trim() + "' and chronic ='" + oldDx.chronic + "';";

        string getchildtables = " select confrelid::regclass, af.attname as fcol,   "+ 
                                " conrelid::regclass, a.attname as col              "+
                                " from pg_attribute af, pg_attribute a,             "+
                                " (select conrelid,confrelid,conkey[i] as conkey, confkey[i] as confkey "+
                                " from (select conrelid,confrelid,conkey,confkey,   "+
                                " generate_series(1,array_upper(conkey,1)) as i     "+
                                " from pg_constraint where contype = 'f') ss) ss2   "+
                                " where af.attnum = confkey and af.attrelid = confrelid and             "+ 
                                " a.attnum = conkey and a.attrelid = conrelid "+
                                " AND confrelid::regclass = 'ICD9'::regclass AND ( af.attname = 'cicd9' OR af.attname ='cdesc');";

        string sf = " update {0} set cicd9= '"+ newdx.icd9 +"' ,cdesc= '"+ newdx.description.ToLower().Trim() +"',"   +
                        " chronic = '"+newdx.chronic+"', modified= '"+ DateTime.Now +"'"                    +
                        " where cicd9 = '"+ oldDx.icd9 +"' and trim(cdesc)= '"+ oldDx.description.ToLower().Trim() +"' and chronic ='"+ oldDx.chronic +"';";

        string delete = "Delete from icd9 where trim(cicd9) = '" + oldDx.icd9.Trim() + "'" +
                        " and trim(cdesc)='" + oldDx.description.Trim() + "' and chronic = '"+ oldDx.chronic +"';";


        // NpsqlConnection is unmanaged code...should use a using() block.
        using (NpgsqlConnection pgConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connect))
        {
            try
            {
                pgConnection.Open();
                // Connection successful

                // Create a new transaction
                using (NpgsqlTransaction pgTransaction = (NpgsqlTransaction)pgConnection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (NpgsqlCommand updateCMD = new NpgsqlCommand(update, pgConnection, pgTransaction))
                        {
                            updateCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        //Commit transaction. Hope it works!  Will fail for unique key violation.
                        pgTransaction.Commit();

                    }
                    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
                    {
                        pgTransaction.Rollback();

                        if (ex.Code == Unique_Violation)            
                        {                                
                            try
                            {
                                using (NpgsqlDataAdapter children = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(getchildtables,pgConnection))   
                                {
                                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                                    children.Fill(ds);

                                    DataView dv = new DataView();
                                    dv.Table = ds.Tables[0];

                                    foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
                                    {
                                        string childtable = (string)drv[2];
                                        string updatechild = String.Format(sf, childtable);

                                        NpgsqlCommand updateCMD = new NpgsqlCommand(updatechild, pgConnection);
                                        int k = updateCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    /* all tables now point to new value. remove old value from parent table. */

                                    NpgsqlCommand deleteCMD = new NpgsqlCommand(delete, pgConnection);
                                    int j = deleteCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (NpgsqlException ex1)
                            {
                                string error = ex1.Message;
                                throw;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                            throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```